# Using Zend_Filter_Input, are Filters or Validators processed first?

Tags: php, zend-framework, input, filter, validation

When using Zend_Filter_Input, are Filters or Validators processed first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from Zend\Filter\Input.php:

```
public function isValid($fieldName = null)
{
    $this->_process();
    (...)
}


protected function _process()
{
    if ($this->_processed === false) {
        $this->_filter();
        $this->_validate();
        $this->_processed = true;
    }
}
```